# Is it possible to have the report/chart filter in a VF page

Tags: visualforce, charts, report-chart

Where could we the out-of-box filters on a VF page? Just like we do at the `report` admin page. So that everyone accesses the VF page, they can manipulate the filter by their own self.

```
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="xxxx"
       filter="{column:'CREATED_DATE',operator:'greaterThan', value:'2017-09-25'}"
    >
    </analytics:reportChart>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to pass the filter values dynamically in your visualforce page?